# How to know what CSS properties are valid for an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a hard time knowing what CSS properties are valid/used for a given HTML element/tag.

I keep expecting to find some resource online that has every element (e.g. `div`, `a`, `p`, etc.), and a list of the CSS properties which can be used with that element. I've found some resources which seem decent  but I notice are missing some valid properties (e.g. [developer-mozilla, table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) missing `table-layout`), and other elements have little to no CSS information.

How am I supposed to know what CSS elements are valid for an element?

Comment: you should only know what CSS is *invalid* for some particular elements. Technically any element can be style by any CSS properties with no restriction but there is some particular cases that you will know when you face them

Comment: In the inspector in chrome, inspect an element, then click the computed tab. There is a toggle to show all inherited attributes. There are many, many attributes you can style. It's worth mentioning that some of them only work together. A `position:static` element won't be changed by `top:10px`, but that's not to say `top:10px` is "invalid"

Comment: Actually, it's a interesting (and valid) question IMO. I dont know why the downvotes

Comment: CSS really has nothing to do with HTML. It's a language that can apply to any XML-like markup language.

Comment: @felipsmartins my guess is that it's asking for resources. So, it falls under OT:seeking recommendations. Still, it's a valid question and I think can be answered, as it's basically about tools developers would use. Then again, it can also be "too broad" because of how much one can write to explain everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.getComputedStyle(element)
```

may be a good place to start. E.g. a paragraph showing all its css attributes (set explicitly and implicitly):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const example = document.getElementById('example');
  const p = window.getComputedStyle(example);
  example.textContent = Object.values(p).join('\n');
  console.log(p);  
})
```

```html
<pre id="example"></pre>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question at all?

Comment: Good answer, this is the correct approach. Even MDN suggests it: *To get the values of all CSS properties for an element you should use Window.getComputedStyle() instead.* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

Comment: I'm not the downvoter. But I think  getComputedStyle() get only applied styles, not all applicable to HTML element

Comment: @felipsmartins Your assumption is wrong.

Comment: @connexo this answer is *clearly* wrong because if you test the code in Chrome you will get properties like `px`,`py` and those are "invalid" for `p` elements since they are designed for SVG elements. Window.getComputedStyle() will return the same properties (all of them) for all the elements. They are simply "valid" properties because they exist (the element is irrelevant here)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Do you mean `rx` and `ry`?

Comment: @AlexanderPresber yes .. was to late to edit my comment when I noticed it (`rx`,`ry`,`cx`,`cy`,`x`,`y`,`d`,`r` etc all for SVG)

Comment: @TemaniAfif True, it returns `border-collapse` as well, which does not make sense, either. Mhm.